# Amend past commit message in Git-Tower

Tags: git, commit, git-amend, git-tower

[image: screenshot]

Change the commit message `be390538` from "**A**" to "**6**" in [Git-Tower](http://git-tower.com)

Comment: You can do that with `rebase` but you would rewrite history and cause problems with others. Think whether this is really necessary or not.

Answer (score 4):

This will rewrite the history and mean its more diffuclt for people who have branched from 7 and 8 to merge back in

The command you want is

`git rebase -i be390538^`

an editor will pop up, in this editor choose the reword option for the commit. save and close
another editor will pop up asking you to choose the working of the new commit (with the wording of the old commit in place)

as a note ^ after a commit means that commits parent